# Make calculations across 2 different data frames

Tags: r, merge

I have 2 data frames DF1 and DF2, then have similar date range and variables names, but for sure the meaning is different.

DF1

```
Date      name1   name2   name3   name4   name5   name6   name7
2022/05  85.37    30.30   108.86  14.67   23.90   77.62   23.30
2022/06  44.00    85.00   113.20  16.28   20.40   56.97   77.85
2022/07  37.36    85.00   113.20  16.28   35.68   74.86   43.34
2022/08  41.34    36.34   184.90  20.70   58.79   30.34   72.38
```

DF2

```
Date      name1   name2   name3   name4   name5   name6   name7
2022/05   100     178    140      100     178     100   140
2022/06   140     140    178      140     140     140   140
2022/07   178     178    140      178     100     178   178
2022/08   178     140    140      140     140     178   178
```

For each variable I need to calculate a share of DF1 from DF2.

```
Date      name1     name2   name3   name4   name5   name6   name7
2022/05   85.37/100    
2022/06   44.00/140     etc.
```

For sure, there is a possibility to merge the files and then use dplyr to calculate the percentage variable by variable, but may be there is a shorter way?

Comment: `DF1[-1] / DF2[-1]` will give the ratios of all columns but the first one. This assumes the columns are in the same order.

Comment: But... i get an error Error in mydata6[-1]/mydata8[-1] : 
  non-numeric argument to binary operator
In addition: Warning message:
Incompatible methods ("Ops.data.table", "Ops.data.frame") for "/". I have checked the variables and in fact they are all numeric for both datasets...

Comment: Sounds like one is a data.frame and one is a data.table. It will work as long as they are both the same. Pick one to convert so it matches the class of the other.

Comment: (And for `data.table` you will need to use `data[, -1]` to drop the first column, not `data[-1]`).

Comment: Thanks! when I solved the issue the code worked perfectly!